# Find the density of random variable $Z=X/Y$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,2]$. I want to find the p.d.f of $Z=X/Y$.

Here is my solution: $$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(X/Y\leq z)=P(X\leq Yz)$$ Since the joint density is the product of the two densities, then we can write: \begin{align}
P(X\leq Yz)& =\int_0^2\int_0^{\min(zy,2)}\frac{1}{4}dxdy\\
& =\int_0^2\frac{1}{4}\min(zy,2)dy\\
\end{align}

Solving out the integral:
$$
\int_0^2\frac{1}{4}\min(zy,2)dy=
\begin{cases}
 \int_0^{2/z}\frac{1}{4}zydy+\int_{2/z}^2\frac{1}{4}2dy&\text{if}\, z\geq 1, \\
 \int_0^2\frac{1}{4}zydy&\text{if}\, z<1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Then I get the distribution
$$
F_Z(z)=
\begin{cases}
 1-1/2z&\text{if}\ z\geq 1, \\
 z/2&\text{if}\, z<1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Diffrentiating, I get the density:
$$
f_Z(z)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2z^2}&\text{if}\, z\geq 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2}&\text{if}\, z<1\\
0&\text{if}\, z<0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Did I do this correctly? I would love some feedback on my attempt.

Comment: I think there's a little problem with your disjunction : it should be $z<1$ vs $z>1$. Consequence ; your distribution function is not continuous at $2$.

Comment: Is there a reason why it should be at $z=1$? I figured I should do $z=2$ since it's a uniform distribution on $[0,2]$.

Comment: Yes : if $z\le 1$, then for all $y\in[0,2]$, $zy\le 2$, so your min is just $zy$. If $z>1$, then you have to cut your integral. You were very close :-)

Comment: Is $z=1$ where we take the cases because $Z$ is a quotient r.v.?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I edited my answer accordingly, is it ok now?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just put $0\le z<1$ on the second line of your answer for the density. You can also check that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_Z(z)dz=1$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS thank you. Could you explain why we would want our disjunction to be at $z=1$?

Comment: Just study $zy\le 2$ and solve for $z$ with parameter $y\in[0,2]$.